# convert xy from autocad to latitude longtitude?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, converters, autocad

i have a file in autocad with somthing like 24,000 points of objects that include the x,y coordination in autocad... so i export all the point to a txt file because i want to have all this point in my database of my site (i am using google maps to see all the point on the map) but, the problem is that the x,y point is not in the currect format like the google maps need...
an exemple for some point:

> 181447.163751433,643530.564881084

, but i need it to be with latitude and longtitude... maybe someone know if there is a formula  to change this xy poiny to longtitude and latitude and i will do it with c# or there some other way to do it?

i didnt got an answer anywere i hope some ont know it.... thanks...
jordan.

Comment: are your points in AutoCad in geographically correct location? Which location does it correspond to? from the example point you provided, it does not look like a valid geographic coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Map3D or civil3D.

1. Create points - Import option - Point file
2. Assign co-ordinate system
3. Export to Google earth or Shp or SDF or any format as you wish.

Let me know how you go.